# Mongoose giving weird result when pulling an element from an array inside an object in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema that looks like :-

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("some_id"), 
    "repDet" : {
        "devIDs" : [
            "dev1_B37", 
            "dev2_B38", 
            "dev3_B26"
        ], 
        "sensors" : [
            "D30"
        ], 
        "triggers" : [
            "initial"
        ]
}
```

I want to pull "dev2_B38" from the array "devIDs" inside the object "repDet".
The following command works in mongo db :-

```
schedules.updateOne({ added_by: currentUser, "repDet.devIDs": "dev2_B38" },{$pull : {"repDet.devIDs": "dev2_B38"}})
```

perfectly.

But the same command doesnt work in mongoose. The mongoose version that I have tried on is 
5.0.18 & 5.7.11.
what it does it removes all the other devIDs from the array and keeps just the "dev_B38" and also converting "devIDs" into a string from an array. The output looks like :-

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("some_id"), 
    "repDet" : {
        "devIDs" : "dev2_B38",
        "sensors" : [
            "D30"
        ], 
        "triggers" : [
            "initial"
        ]
}
```

I have tried updateOne, update, findOneAndUpdate all of these.
I also tried modifying it like :-

```
schedules.updateOne({ added_by: currentUser, "repDet.devIDs": "dev2_B38" },{$pull : {"repDet" {"devIDs": "dev2_B38"}}})
```

but still it gave me the same result.

The exact schema is :-

```
var scheduleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String },
    message: { type: String },

    devID: { type: String },
    sensors: [{
      sensorId: String,
      sensorName: String,
      unit: String
    }],

    selectedContacts: [{
      _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Contact' },
      name: String,
      mobiles: [Number],
      emails: [String]
    }],
    repDet: { type: Object },
    invocationTime: { type: String },
    invocationDays: Array,
    startTime: { type: String },
    endTime: { type: String },
    interval: { type: Number },
    repeat: { type: Number },
    url: String
  });
```

Kindly help me with this.
Thank you

Comment: you want pull that array only right?

Comment: i want to pull just one dev id from the array.

Comment: @BilalS10 Your syntax is changing here `{"repDet" {"devIDs": "dev2_B38"}}`?? Whether it should be `{"repDet.devIDs": "dev2_B38"}`

Comment: You need to use absolute object structure. So try this way `schedules.updateOne({ added_by: currentUser, "repDet.devIDs": "dev2_B38" },{$pull : {"repDet":{devIDs: "dev2_B38" }}})
`

Comment: @Ashh I have already tried the same. see the modified code that i have mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Subburaj I tried first with {"repDet.devIDs": "dev2_B38"} and this works on mongo db but not in mongoose. I tried {"repDet" {"devIDs": "dev2_B38"}} as it was mentioned in one of the answers for a similar question.

Comment: @BilalS10 Then the issue is somewhere else. The code you shown above works in mongoose. Could you edit your question and show the schema.

Comment: sure will do that

Comment: I have added the schema definition in the question. @Ashh could you please go through it.

Comment: I was able to solve through a workaround as the updation of one field was not happening. I guess it was because the schema did not mention the individual field items and their data types. 
Thank you guyz for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
schedules.updateOne({ _id: currentUser},
 {$pull : {"repDet.devIDs":"dev1_B37"}})
```

try this

Comment: this I have already tried.